# Which Use Of Hardware's Character for generate Software Lock?

Tags: c#, java, wmi

I want to create a software lock with wmi in windows.
I checked very hardware character such:
processorId,SerialNumber(HDisk),MaxClockSpeed,...

but some this Characters are useless on Different Systems.

Which Use Of Hardware's Characters be Run Software lock on all systems?

Comment: Java goes to great lengths to avoid or hide hardware specific code, which is the opposite of what you want. ;) Why not use a combination of the attributes available (even if not all are available on every system)

Answer (score 3):

Short Answer: None.

The user could always let the software ran within a virtual machine, allowing to fake the whole hardware. On the other hand, legal users are maybe going to upgrade their machine (e.g. changing the mainboard or hdd) which could lead to a change of any hardware parameter, which would lead to angry customers, cause they have to contact you to get their legal version to a running state again.

If you really need some kind of hard to hack locking take an USB dongle, but consider a strategy if the customer calls for lost dongles.